# Do_shortcode before send email content

Tags: plugins, shortcode, email

I'm having a little problem figuring out how to execute shortcodes stored in a mail content option of a plugin.

The thing is, I have a field in my options page named '_message' that works with WYSIWYG Editor, and I want to save shortcodes there and then execute them before send the email.

There is some way of detect shortcodes in strings?. Ex:

`$message = 'blablabla [sale_products] blablaba';
do_shortcode($message);`

If you have another suggestion of how can this be done, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$message = apply_filters('the_content', $your_data);
```

I think this filter could handle the shortcode. (not tested)

Answer (score 0):

While this is not very obvious, [`do_shortcode`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) is usually applied as a filter on a function that generates a certain text. It is, for instance, defined as a standard filter on `the_content` like this:

```
add_filter ('the_content','do_shortcode');
```

So, the trick is to define it as a filter on [`get_option`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) in your plugin. If you look at the source code of `get_option` you'll see that on the last line there is a filter applied, the name of which depends on the name of the option. Suppose the name of the option that stores the message is `my_message` You would have something like this:

```
add_filter ('option_my_message','do_shortcode');
```

That should mean that if you have `$message = get_option('my_message')` in your plugin, you would get it with shortcodes evaluated.